# Shrink non-OS windows partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-server-2012, resizing

I am having difficulty shrinking a partition on our file server (Windows 2012r2).
This server has a single physical drive, with two partitions.

The C: partition holds the OS is 40gb and almost out of space.

The D: partition holds our files, is 800gb, 319gb free.

I would like to shrink the D: partition by 30gb, and then expand the C: partition by 30gb

[Image of attempting to shrink the partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS12X.png)

When I click OK, the server thinks for a couple of minutes and then spits out an error stating "There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation"

If I check in eventvwr.exe, I find an entry like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FyhM.png)

This is just a normal file.  There is no reason I can find for it to be "immovable".  If I make a copy of the file, delete the old file and rename the new file, then try and shrink again, I get a similar entry in eventvwr.exe, but with a different file listed.

I have tried defragging, which does not help.  I don't want to use a non-windows option (such as gparted) to avoid the chance of data deletion.  I REALLY don't want to have to backup the D:\, blow it away, expand the C: drive and then recreate the D: drive.  This is the file server for our whole company and having to recreate the shares/NTFS permissions would be a bear.

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically list unmovable files on a windows volume?  If I could get a list of all the files, it would be easy to script an option to copy/delete/rename all those files.  That might be the fix I'm looking for...

Any help/suggestions would be greatly apprecaited.

Taylor

Comment: you don't want to have to backup the D drive? right there you're wrong to start with.  Second .. you will not be able to expand the C partition while the D partition is in the way. *Unless* your drive is setup as Dynamic. Third GParted is not likely to damage data but again, point 1 you should backup regardless, if you move the D partition to another drive, expand C then shrink and move D back you should be fine.  Yes it requires your server be cleanly shut down and then booted from gparted iso, but its safer than performing actions on a live production server.

Comment: TG2, I didn't say I don't want to backup the D drive, I said " I REALLY don't want to have to backup the D:\, blow it away, expand the C: drive and then recreate the D: drive"  I don't want to have to do that entire process.  I would definitely backup the D drive before performing any maintenance on the physical disk such as GParted.

Comment: RW - Sorry .. so noted .. so.. still comes back to how did you expect to expand C?  Because shrink starts at the end of the partition, where there is usually no data (also why they suggest defrag first as it may consolidate)   Either way, best bet ... temporary drive, move the D partition there, then expand C, then shrink D, and last move it back. ... windows has gotten worse about its expansion from keeping older and multiple versions of programs.. to which, another option move install.wim https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/11/27/free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2012/